# Reasons for installing a fresh copy of Windows Server 2003 and Active Directory?

Tags: networking

Just need some reasons why i would or would not install Active Directory? Can you give me a few scenario's? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Would:

Scenario 1:  You have 10 workstations.  You have 10 users.  Each user can log in to any workstation and find their files and settings the same.  Roaming profiles.

Scenario 2:  You have 10 workstations.  You have 10 users.  When you want to change passwords you don't want to have to log in to each machine and change it 10 times.  Centralized auth.

Would not:

Scenario 1:  You have a small network and it's just not worth the hassle.  You don't log in to each others computers anyway.

Scenario 2:  You like Linux and/or don't want to pay Microsoft a per user tax.  You implement Samba to get your centralized auth and roaming profiles.